# Where's my invalid character (ORA-00911)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to insert `CLOB`s into a database (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727521/)). I can't quite figure out what's wrong. I have a list of about 85 clobs I want to insert into a table. Even when inserting only the first clob I get `ORA-00911: invalid character`. I can't figure out how to get the statement out of the `PreparedStatement` before it executes, so I can't be 100% certain that it's right, but if I got it right, then it should look exactly like this:

```
insert all
  into domo_queries values ('select 
substr(to_char(max_data),1,4) as year,
substr(to_char(max_data),5,6) as month,
max_data
from dss_fin_user.acq_dashboard_src_load_success
where source = ''CHQ PeopleSoft FS''')
select * from dual;
```

Ultimately, this [`insert all`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php) statement would have a lot of `into`'s, which is why I just don't do a regular `insert` statement. I don't see an invalid character in there, do you? (Oh, and that code above **runs fine when I run it in my sql developer tool**.) And I if I remove the semi-colon in the `PreparedStatement`, it throws an `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` error.

In any case, here's my code for executing the query (and the values of the variables for the example above).

```
public ResultSet executeQuery(String connection, String query, QueryParameter... params) throws DataException, SQLException {
  // query at this point = "insert all
                          //into domo_queries values (?)
                          //select * from dual;"
  Connection conn = ConnectionPool.getInstance().get(connection);
  PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  for (int i = 1; i <= params.length; i++) {
    QueryParameter param = params[i - 1];
    switch (param.getType()) { //The type in the example is QueryParameter.CLOB
      case QueryParameter.CLOB:
        Clob clob = CLOB.createTemporary(conn, false, oracle.sql.CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
        clob.setString(i, "'" + param.getValue() + "'");
        //the value of param.getValue() at this point is:
        /*
         * select 
         * substr(to_char(max_data),1,4) as year,
         * substr(to_char(max_data),5,6) as month,
         * max_data
         * from dss_fin_user.acq_dashboard_src_load_success
         * where source = ''CHQ PeopleSoft FS''
         */
        pstmt.setClob(i, clob);
        break;
      case QueryParameter.STRING:
        pstmt.setString(i, "'" + param.getValue() + "'");
        break;
    }
  }
  ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); //Obviously, this is where the error is thrown
  conn.commit();
  ConnectionPool.getInstance().release(conn);
  return rs;
}
```

Is there anything I'm just missing big time?

Comment: Can you view the PreparedStatement as a string to see what it contains?

Comment: I mentioned that in the post. I can't figure out how to do that. All I see on the internet is that it's pretty complicated for some reason...

Comment: Some JDBC drivers allow toString() to show you the query from a PreparedStatement and some don't. Not sure about Oracle.

Comment: @DanArmstrong, unfortunately, that's not the case here. I get a `oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@8870a2` on a `toString()` print out.

Comment: Does Oracle support query logging. If so then you could see the query when it hits the server.

Comment: Yeah, it does in `v$sql`. But apparently it's not logged unless it doesn't throw an error...

Comment: What is the content of `query` that is passed to the method? It would need to have placeholders for each and every parameter you pass. And I don't understand why you are adding single quotes to the value that is passed to `clob.setString()`. One of the reasons to use PreparedStatements is that you don't have to worry about quoting.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, good point, I forgot I added those single quotes there in my debugging. Unfortunately, that didn't solve the problem. The content of the `query` is described above in the original question. I show it in the code. And it runs fine in my developer tool...

Comment: but it does not contain any `?` as parameter markers. Without those, the PreparedStatement is not going to work. For each PreparedStatement.setXXX() call there must be a coresponding `?` in the prepared SQL (and that must not be enclosed in single quotes)

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. I'll update the post to show what the value of `query` is.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

If you use the string literal exactly as you have shown us, the problem is the `;` character at the end. You may not include that in the query string in the JDBC calls.

As you are inserting only a single row, a regular `INSERT` should be just fine even when inserting multiple rows. Using a batched statement is probable more efficient anywy. No need for `INSERT ALL`. Additionally you don't need the temporary clob and all that. You can simplify your method to something like this (assuming I got the parameters right):

```
String query1 = "select substr(to_char(max_data),1,4) as year, " + 
  "substr(to_char(max_data),5,6) as month, max_data " +
  "from dss_fin_user.acq_dashboard_src_load_success " + 
  "where source = 'CHQ PeopleSoft FS'";

String query2 = ".....";

String sql = "insert into domo_queries (clob_column) values (?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
StringReader reader = new StringReader(query1);
pstmt.setCharacterStream(1, reader, query1.length());
pstmt.addBatch();

reader = new StringReader(query2);
pstmt.setCharacterStream(1, reader, query2.length());
pstmt.addBatch();

pstmt.executeBatch();   
con.commit();
```

Comment: Yeah, someone else mentioned that too. When I take it out I get an `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` error...

Comment: @kentcdodds: why are you using `insert all` in the first place? A normal insert should be just fine.

Comment: In my original question I mention that what you see there is only a test to make sure that only one insert gets run. In all actuality, there will be about 85 inserts in this statement.

Comment: @kentcdodds: see my edit. I think you are better off using batched statements and simplifying your CLOB handling.

Comment: Oh shoot! That totally worked! Thanks so much! :D Really appreciate the help.

Comment: To add, many think that `;` is statement terminator in SQL on Oracle. It isn't. The `;` at an end of statement is used by the client (for example SQL*Plus) to tell where the statement ends and then sends the statement but not the ';' to the Oracle server. In SQL*PLus, with defaults try `select * from dual; --semicolon to terminate`. You will get a `2` prompt for the rest of the command, because SQL*Plus only uses the `;` if it is the last character in a line, but `select * from dual --weird that this works;` The `;` appears to part of a comment, but still "terminates" the statement.

Comment: PL/SQL does use `;` as a statement terminator, but it is a language from Oracle's implementation of SQL.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance: the `;` **is** defined as the statement termination character by the SQL standard. But to increase the confusion regarding this: SQL Server (not the client!) **requires** some statements to be sent with a `;` at the end even through JDBC. And apparently it also sometimes requires the `;` at the front of the statement.

Comment: I tried to make it clear I was discussing Oracle's implementation of SQL, not standard SQL. SQL Server is wacky with sometimes requiring a `;` to separate statements, but not having required a `;` all along.

Comment: Comment above should read: _PL/SQL does use `;` as a statement terminator, but it is a language_ separate _from Oracle's implementation of SQL._

Comment: just a ; was killing me

Comment: I had a ; at the end of an insert query and it made my life miserable for 4 hours! I was trying to do a batch insert of 2000+rows from java to mySql.

Comment: Is there any official documentation article related to this weird exception, related to why there is no need for semicolon and when there is need for it?

Answer (score 6):

Of the top of my head, can you try to use the 'q' operator for the string literal

something like

```
insert all
  into domo_queries values (q'[select 
substr(to_char(max_data),1,4) as year,
substr(to_char(max_data),5,6) as month,
max_data
from dss_fin_user.acq_dashboard_src_load_success
where source = 'CHQ PeopleSoft FS']')
select * from dual;
```

Note that the single quotes of your predicate are not escaped, and the string sits between q'[...]'.

Comment: Awesome, I forgot about `q'[]'`. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason may be if any one of table column have an **underscore(_)** in its name . That is considered as invalid characters by the JDBC . Rename the column by a ALTER Command and change in your code SQL , that will fix .

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provide some explanation for [ORA-00911](https://www.databasestar.com/ora-00911). You can got this explanation after executing SQL request in Oracle SQL Developer.

> ORA-00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
> *Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
> letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
> character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
> any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
> (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
> delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
> Reference Manual

But in your case it seems to be double ' character