# Error: ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: sql, oracle, visual-studio, oracle11g

This is query when run from TOAD works perfectly, but when I run from the Visual studio give me the error 'ORA-00911: invalid character'. This is how looks my query:

```
INSERT into TRB (ID, ID_REF, DATE, STATUS, INSERT_DATE,
                           ID_DD_REF, USER, VERIFY_DATE, VERIFY_USER) 

select 11, 337470,
       to_date('22.11.2016','DD.MM.YYYY'),
       'O',
       CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-11-22 14:28:24.260','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9') AS DATE),
       8552,
       'test',
       NVL(CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9') AS DATE),''),
       '' from dual  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM TRB WHERE ID = 11);
```

Comment: I am running from VIsual Studio 10 and progam is in vb code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the semicolon ; at the end.

Also, look at this question: [Where's my invalid character (ORA-00911)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728377/wheres-my-invalid-character-ora-00911)

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you a lot.