# Run ddl script from file in Groovy

Tags: database, jdbc, groovy, ddl, execute

I working with Spock and Groovy in order to test my application. I should need to run a ddl script before to run every test. 
To execute the script from Groovy I am using the following code:

```
    def scriptToExecute = './src/test/groovy/com/sql/createTable.sql'
    def sqlScriptToExecuteString = new File(scriptToExecute).text
    sql.execute(sqlScriptToExecuteString)
```

The createTable.sql is a complex script that do several drop and create operation ( of course it is multiline ).  When I try to execute it I got the following exception:

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

To notice that the ddl is correct since that it has been checked running it on the same DB that I am connecting with groovy.

Any Idea how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Do you have a trailing `;` in the statement(s) in your ddl? [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10728434/6730571)

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00911.php

Comment: @HuguesMoreau I understand that ; is the problem but if I don't use ; between 2 create statement then I get: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Comment: Yeah sorry obviously you'll have multiple statements separated with semicolons... Initially I meant just the one at the very end, but even without it, it would not work (not supported by JDBC I believe), so I made a different suggestion, as an answer because it does not fit in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think JDBC does not support this, but there are tools/libraries that could help, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1044837/6730571) for Java.

In Groovy, using this [JDBC script runner](https://github.com/BenoitDuffez/ScriptRunner) would be something like:

```
Connection con = ....
def runner = new ScriptRunner(con, [booleanAutoCommit], [booleanStopOnerror])
def scriptFile = new File("createTable.ddl")
scriptFile.withReader { reader ->
    runner.runScript(reader)
}
```

Or, if your script is "simple enough" (ie no comments, no semicolons other than separating statements...), you can load the text, split it around `;` and execute using `sql.withBatch`, something like that:

```
def scriptText = new File("createTable.ddl").text
sql.withBatch { stmt ->
    scriptText.split(';').each { order ->
        stmt.addBatch order.trim()
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited `ScriptRunner.java` to add a `package <name>` statement, compiled, packed it in `.jar`, put it on Jenkins classpath, used `import <package>` and its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get it done in JDBC (See Hugues' answer), consider executing `sqlplus` from your Groovy program.

```
["sqlplus", CREDENTIALS, "@"+scriptToExecute].execute()
```

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, using JDBC is not a requirement! Good idea