# Connecting combobox in javafx with database

Tags: database, oracle, javafx

I've tried connecting combobox in javafx with database but i'm not able to do it...Here's my code of fxml controller and fxml file

It isn't showing any kind of errors but still not working...

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

 @FXML
    private Button button;
    final ObservableList options=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ComboBox combobox=new ComboBox(options);
    @Override // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
         try{
             Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
             Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","hetvi9398");
             ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT username FROM typebuddy;");
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    options.add(rs.getString("username"));
                }

             rs.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
         //combobox.setItems(null);
        combobox.setItems(options);
    }
}
```

and this is my fxml tag for combobox

```
<ComboBox fx:id="combobox" editable="true" layoutX="1010.0" layoutY="56.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Username" />
```

Comment: You don't seem to be displaying the combo box anywhere. You just create it and fill it with data from the database.

Comment: So what should I do to display it??

Comment: @fabian I tried what you told me but it din't print anything so what should I do now??

Comment: "I just got a list of errors". We cannot help unless you provide the necessary info to identify the issue.

Comment: Okay the main error is about Java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character..

Comment: As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10728434/4240433) suggests just remove the `;`  from your sql query to get rid of the `SQLException`

Comment: Thank you so much @Markus K .It worked so well...